# Ping timeout time

Tags: vb.net

I have a fully working ping code, but I found out, if the ping return time is to high, it will get marked as offline.

Code:

```
 Try
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(PRIBox.Text) Then
            'Online
            If GetPingMs(PRIBox.Text) < 125 Then
                'Good ping
                PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
            Else
                'Bad ping
                PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
            End If
        Else
            PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
            'Offline
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
```

Is there anyway to have it not timeout until like, 1500ms, or something like that, while still using this function?

Addition function I use for the *long round-trips*

```
Public Function GetPingMs(ByVal address As String) As Long
    Dim ping As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    Return ping.Send(address).RoundtripTime
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, sorry for wasting all your times!

```
 Try
    If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(PRIBox.Text, 1500) Then '<----
        'Online
        If GetPingMs(PRIBox.Text) < 125 Then
            'Good ping
            PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
        Else
            'Bad ping
            PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
        End If
    Else
        PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
        'Offline
    End If
Catch
End Try
```